# How do you setState to empty when components that rely on this data throw errors without a placeholder?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

**Problem Overview :**

1. Building personal website with a Homepage.js, a Sidebar.js component, and a Project.js component.
2. Project components are mapped on Homepage from a project list array of objects.
3. Sidebar.js component will open and display active project info when a Project component is clicked on.
4. App.js has activeProject state, with a default set to first project in list so sidebar doesn't throw errors.
5. End result is that Sidebar displays correct project title, info, and video src (inspect mode) on Project click, but the video itself is wrong and always shows the placeholder's video set on App.js

[Props passes right info, wrong video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYgSD.png)

**Details :**

In my App.js I set activeProject to the first project in my list as a default, via it's title.

```
const [activeProject, setActiveProject] = useState(ListOfProjects[0].title);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <HomePage 
        isOpen={isOpen}
        setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
        activeProject={activeProject}
        setActiveProject={setActiveProject}
      />
      <Sidebar
        isOpen={isOpen}
        setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
        activeProject={activeProject}
      />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
```

My projects are mapped out on my Homepage.js

```
<div className="project-list">
        {ListOfProjects.map((obj) => (
               <ProjectItem
                      key={obj.id}
                      title={obj.title}
                      video={obj.video}
                      videoAlt={obj.videoAlt}
                      liveLink={obj.liveLink}
                      codeLink={obj.codeLink}
                      isOpen={isOpen}
                      setIsOpen={setIsOpen}
                      activeProject={activeProject}
                      setActiveProject={setActiveProject}
               />
        ))}
</div>
```

Each project component has a click event to open the sidebar component with extra project information based on the project title that was clicked on.

```
const showSidebar = () => {
        setActiveProject(title);
        setIsOpen(!isOpen);
}
```

On Sidebar.js I have this list of props being pulled from the project with a title that matches the current active project set state.

```
const {title, liveLink, codeLink, video, videoAlt, tags, details, challenges, lessons} = ListOfProjects.find((project) => {
        return project.title === activeProject;
});
```

The result is that the sidebar component displays the correct title, project info, and even the right video src when shown in the inspection tool, but the project video is always of the first project in the list. Here is my website for more context (https://bryanfink.dev)

**Things I have tried :**

I tried changing the App.js activeProject state placeholder to the second project.

```
const [activeProject, setActiveProject] = useState(ListOfProjects[1].title);
```

This resulted in the Sidebar showing the correct project title, info, and video src(inspect mode) but now the video always shows the second project's video.

Then I tried changing the App.js activeProject state placeholder to ""

```
const [activeProject, setActiveProject] = useState("");
```

But this results in errors in the sidebar.

```
Sidebar.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of '_Projects_listOfProjects__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.find(...)' as it is undefined
```

Comment: hey! if you destruct an object and try to extract an unavailable field it will cause an error, I wish it had optional chaining but there isn't just yet. You need to validate the object and/or field you try to destruct first.

Comment: So, based on the screenshot you provided, when you inspect the video on the browser, you see the correct src but the wrong video?

Comment: Correct @JayF., and I know the src works because it displays the right video on the Homepage.

Comment: @BryanF I suggested an answer. I hope this fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, [the find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may return undefined if it can not find the data. So you can not destruct undefined. Adding `|| {}` will check if `ListOfProjects.find((project) => { return project.title === activeProject; })` is undefined, it will change to an empty object `{}`

```
const {title, liveLink, codeLink, video, videoAlt, tags, details, challenges, lessons} = ListOfProjects.find((project) => {
        return project.title === activeProject;
}) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, create a default project

```js
const defaultProject = {
title: "",
liveLink: "",
}
const {title, liveLink, codeLink, video, videoAlt, tags, details, challenges, lessons} = ListOfProjects.find((project) => {
        return project.title === activeProject;
}) || defaultProject;
```

Also, make sure the `title` is unique or the `.find` will be returning wrong project.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It has produced an interesting result in Sidebar. Now the video is missing altogether, but the inspection tool still shows the correct video src.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is not the way you pass the data to your component. The issue is, when you rerender your component, it changes the `src` in your video `<source />` tag but it does not actually reload the video, thus you see an old or wrong video even with the correct URL. I would suggest `load()` the video with each call to your child component that shows the video. For example call load in useEffect whenever the video source changed:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("video").load();
}, [])
```

This will force the `video` to reload with the new `src`.

EDIT:

I cloned your project and the issue indeed is re-loading the video with the new source. Here is the solution. In your Sidebar.js add the following `useEffect` and add `className="sidebar-video"` to your `<video />` tag. That should do it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector(".sidebar-video").load();
}, [title]);
```

Comment: I think that is a very smart suggestion. Unfortunately the video is still the same

Comment: @BryanF Is this on Git so we can take a look?

Comment: Yes, here is a link https://github.com/BryanMF87/bryanmf87.github.io

Comment: @BryanF I have updated my answer and checked locally. It seems to solve the problem.